# I'm facing this problem in android studio.I have downloaded the files mentioned in links, where to put paste those file

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, android-studio-3.6

Launching lib\main.dart on LS 5016 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 8174407; received: 2359280
  >   Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5248142; received: 4456416
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27m 34s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: do you have internet connection?try again with internet and tell me if it works

Comment: Are you running any proxy within Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter `Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'`, I usually invalidate cache , restart, clean and rebuild project. Strangely, the problem is solved just like that.

Anyway, if you want to add more dependencies, you can choose File > Project Structure > Dependencies.

Hope it help!